# Why can't I access a field in a class using a variable?

Tags: typescript

Sorry if the title is badly worded, but I can't think of a better way to say it. I think I can show it better with my example.

```
let entry: {[dkey: string]: any} = {};
```

[image: 1][image: 2]

Basically entry is an object with a string key and value of any type. The variable "i" used in the code is an instance of class with a public field called "avg". When I do entry["123"] = i["avg"], everything is fine. However, if I define a variable called entryValueKey that equals to the same string "avg", and call entry[j] (j is also a string) = i[entryValueKey], it gives me this error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `const entryValueKey = "avg";` instead of `let entryValueKey = "avg";`.

When you use `const`, TypeScript knows that `entryValueKey` will always be the exact string `"avg"` and will let you use it to access `i` since `i` has an `avg` field.  When you use `let`, TypeScript infers the type of `entryValueKey` as just `string` (i.e. it could be any string in the whole universe) and thus it won't allow you to use it to access `i` because it might be a string which doesn't match an existing property of `i`.

See [the literal types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I probably should've included this in the post, but I just used "avg" as an example for simplicity since I thought it's all gonna be the same. Reality is that those two lines are in a for loop and entryValueKey is changing with each loop, but will always be a string that represents a field in the class "i", and "i" has multiple fields. How should I go about doing this? I can update the post with new pictures if that helps?

Comment: Ah, I see. Because you're making these strings dynamically, there's probably no great way to get things to work super cleanly. Check out this answer though, it's essentially addressing your exact situation - verifying that an arbitrary string is actually a property of an object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67552533/3124288

Comment: Thanks, it seems I figured it out. I did added "as keyof DataEntry" where DataEntry is the class of i after "let entryValueKey" and it worked. :D

Comment: Yes, that'll work! It won't prevent a possible runtime error from happening though if `entryValueKey` does accidentally end up being an invalid key, so you might also want to check something like `if (entryValueKey in i) { entry[j] = i[entryValueKey]; }` or something similar just to be on the safe side!