# Typescript says I can not use an already checked key to index an object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a type guard function that will determine if certain unknown value is an object with certain string keys.
For that reason, first I have to check that obj is of type object (and for some weird js reason, that it is not null too), that makes sense.
Then I make sure that certain string is a property of the object using the in operator. Last, I use the already checked property to check the type value, and there is where typescript complains saying that I can not use the key to index an unknown object. Isn't the `in` operator taking care of this already?

```js
function hasStringProps<TKeys extends string, Res extends { [k in TKeys]: string }>(
  keys: ReadonlyArray<TKeys>,
  obj: unknown,
): obj is Res {
  if (obj == null || typeof obj !== 'object') return false;
  return keys.every((k) => k in obj && typeof obj[k] === 'string'); 
                                      // ^ Type 'TKeys' cannot be used to index type 'object'.

}
```

Comment: Yep, the predicate `key in object` does not appease TS. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551991/narrowing-a-string-to-a-key-of-an-object

Comment: The `in` operator doesn't narrow the way you want; there's a (fairly old at this point) request for such a feature at [ms/TS#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732); until such a feature is implemented you just have to work around it; you might as well just write `typeof (obj as any)[k] === 'string'`, or see the answer to the linked question for more options.

Answer (score 0):

I think most sensical/simplest way to fix this is to define input parameter as `obj: any`:

```js
function hasStringProps<TKeys extends string, Res extends { [k in TKeys]: string }>(
  keys: ReadonlyArray<TKeys>,
  obj: any,
): obj is Res
{
  if (obj == null || typeof obj !== 'object') return false;
  return keys.every((k) => k in obj && typeof obj[k] === 'string');
}
```