# Unable to do a union type involving multiple enums

Tags: angular, typescript

A simple example:

```
export enum EnumA {
  A = 'a',
}

export enum EnumB {
  A = 'b',
}

export class SomeEntity {
  id: string;

  type: EnumA | EnumB;
}

const foo = (seArray: SomeEntity[]) => {
  seArray.forEach((se) => {
    Object.values(EnumA).includes(se.type)
  })
}
```

But I get error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'EnumA | EnumB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EnumA'.   Type 'EnumB' is not assignable to type 'EnumA'.
```

Looking at the [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) I'm not sure why this is happening as se.type is the value of one of the enums of which it is union typed. Is there some special thing about enums I am missing?

Comment: This is about `includes()` and not enums per se; there are existing q/a pairs about this; I’ll link them when I get off mobile

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033854/why-does-the-argument-for-array-prototype-includessearchelement-need-the-same For example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript doesn't know that you intended for `Object.values(EnumA)` to be an array of `EnumA` *or* `EnumB`; it assumes you wanted it to be an array of just `EnumA`s and so is trying to helpfully point out that `se.type` isn't there. You can fix it by explicitly specifying a wider type for `Object.values(EnumA)`, for instance like this:

```
const foo = (seArray: SomeEntity[]) => {
  seArray.forEach((se) => {
    const values: (EnumA | EnumB)[]  = Object.values(EnumA);
    values.includes(se.type);
  })
}
```