# readonly array union cannot be searched

Tags: typescript

I want to search an element inside an readonly array union

```js
const areas = {
  area1: {
    adjacencies: [2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  area2: {
    adjacencies: [6, 7, 8]
  }
} as const;
let area: keyof typeof areas;
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  area = "area1";
} else {
  area = "area2"
}

// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
areas[area].adjacencies.includes(3);
```

I also tried `indexOf`, but it didn't work either. And I found the `includes` type is `ReadonlyArray<T>.includes(searchElement: never, fromIndex: number | undefined): boolean` .

I suppose the `includes` type should be the union of the elements of two readonly array, just like below:

```js
const areas = {
  area1: {
    adjacencies: [2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  area2: {
    adjacencies: [6, 7, 8]
  }
} as const;

type ValueOf<T extends object> = T[keyof T];
type Values = ValueOf<ValueOf<typeof areas>>
type ElementUnion = Values[number];

let area: keyof typeof areas;
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  area = "area1";
} else {
  area = "area2"
}

areas[area].adjacencies.includes(3);
```

How can I apply `ElementUnion` to `includes` or `indexOf`??

Here is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwKZwjAvDA3gWAFAzzJwCMAXNvoYXACYBWcwSYwAlkhBQNoBMANDADMggCyCArAF0qMAL79ZiFLwq4C1Oo2asOXGNwBsggOyCAHDI1z8c+GlCQoAbnz4oATwAOSGADU4ABsAVyQAeQAzAB4AFRgkAA8oFlo0EAAjeiRgKAA+DBgY7gBrJA8QCMKpVzxPH38g0LRMAJDw6NbQyKi6pAqiFAhc3PdvXwBRQKQAWxYoAFUwNnACzs5uMGDp9KQEarc8KdhlOApS8sre-pOIGrZKgAoAWTgoAAsAOgQ4MFoQaYeAEoYFEYAAGD4SYHqGjEAoAIhOJHhNTsSECEF8MIGcARJ148NsBxu3BOUg+WiYLHYnA+bFYIVonAeQkBziAA)

Comment: To elaborate, in my real code, the object `areas` lays in `CommonData` module, therefore I use `as const` notation to get a better type inferrence.

Comment: To me it looks like a bug which should be reported. If you do - can you please put the link to your question (and tag me to subscribe)

Comment: @zerkms Sure, I'll go check the Typescript github page and see if there's any related issues when I am available.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520

Comment: Also a duplicate or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035048/251311

Answer (score 1):

When you do `as const` you tell typescript "even if encounter a literal like 0 or "hello", rather than inferring it as a general number or string, infer it literally".

So unless both of the arrays has the element you search for, it wont work.

```js
const areas = {
  area1: {
    adjacencies: [2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  area2: {
    adjacencies: [6, 7, 8, 3]
  }
} as const;

type ValueOf<T extends object> = T[keyof T];
type Values = ValueOf<ValueOf<typeof areas>>
type ElementUnion = Values[number];

let area: keyof typeof areas;
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  area = "area1";
} else {
  area = "area2"
}

areas[area].adjacencies.includes(3);
```

Notice how I added a 3 to the second array.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwKZwjAvDA3gWAFAzzJwCMAXNvoYXACYBWcwSYwAlkhBQNoBMANDADMggCyCArAF0qMAL79ZiFLwq4C1Oo2asOXGNwBsggOyCAHIKEyNc-HPhpQkKAG58+KAE8ADkhgAanAANgCuSADyAGYAPAAqMEgAHlAstGggAEb0SMBQAHwYMHHcANZIXiBRxVLueN5+gSHhaJhBYZGx7eHRMQ1IVUQoEPn5nr7+AKLBSAC2LFAAqmBs4EXdnNxgobOZSAi1HngzsMpwFOWV1f2DZxB1bNUAFACycFAAFgB0CHBgtCBZk8AJQwGIwAAMXwkoPUNGIRQARGcSIi6g4kMEIP44UM4EizrxEfYjnduGcpF8tEwWOxOF82KwwrROE8hMDXEA)

Edit:

Look at the signature of the function, only the union of the arrays can be passed to it.

```js
(method) ReadonlyArray<T>.includes(searchElement: 3, fromIndex: number | undefined): boolean
```

Edit 2:
Example:

```js
const areas = {
  area1: {
    adjacencies: [2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  area2: {
    adjacencies: [6, 7, 8]
  }
} as const;

type ValueOf<T extends object> = T[keyof T];
type Values = ValueOf<ValueOf<typeof areas>>
type ElementUnion = Values[number];

let area: keyof typeof areas;

if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  area = "area1";
} else {
  area = "area2"
}

// uh oh, .adjacencies can be either one of the arrays
// if the variable was declared without as const, the function would accept a number
// however since that it not the case, typescript takes the intersection
// (elements present in both arrays) as literal arguments
areas[area].adjacencies.includes(3);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (area === 'area1') {
  // here typescript knows what the elements are
  // but since the variable was declared as const, only literal values
  // that are in the array can be passed to the function
  //                          v Hover over this
  areas[area].adjacencies.includes(2);
} else {
  //                          v Hover over this
  areas[area].adjacencies.includes(6);
}

// Direct access
//                         v Hover over this
areas.area1.adjacencies.includes(2);
//                         v Hover over this
areas.area2.adjacencies.includes(6);
//                         v Hover over this
areas['area1'].adjacencies.includes(2)
//                         v Hover over this
areas['area2'].adjacencies.includes(6)
```

View in playground for hovers

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwKZwjAvDA3gWAFAzzJwCMAXNvoYXACYBWcwSYwAlkhBQNoBMANDADMggCyCArAF0qMAL79ZiFLwq4C1Oo2asOXGNwBsggOyCAHDI1z8c+GlCQoAbnz4oATwAOSGADU4ABsAVyQAeQAzAB4AFRgkAA8oFlo0EAAjeiRgKAA+DBgY7gBrJA8QCMKpVzxPH38g0LRMAJDw6NbQyKi6pAqiFAhc3PdvXwBRQKQAWxYoAFUwNnACzs5uMGDp9KQEarc8KdhlOApS8sre-pOIGvw2SoAKAFk4KAALADoEODBaEGmjwAlDAojAAAyfCQg9Q0YgFABEJxICJqdiQgQgvlhAzgiJOvARtgOAHoSTBgu8YCB3oJPlomCx2JwYMBfjAdvE2B9dtSwL5+jyiD8PBB8GSYA8YEKAG6INhwdJTGAAd1QMFo2UCyloqu57xAwWODnA0EEQoiwVYUGWYFVhsCuqYzC8xxgm22u3F5INKqQMt5EDYrF8HzektgYBAsCFbKx5rGEGACDYrulcFKaCFweSCCxOVt3pgjwxMzmaC8yCxYFgwY50apiBFEBB6sC3N2QSIAHMtuX8DduCcpPSGIzdJxPsHgCFNRBHkIgXc8GTV2v1xvN1vtzvt-cnicMOhMAByZEnmGyCXvXahxPJ1OwYpRlVoFXvcNC0uzGtoZRX8l0iNGAgxDaUbxgOUU0VZU1TQTUZx1exWVNKBBHAQIPBgdtcy7OU2jFDQJTDY5kElO0hSbOAsLZO1OS8VAsV1KAQHA3xLWtQsiPJaheL4-iBJlGAAAkQADBBqXE8C2EIuFBiHYgRwZHRmQgKdWFnThHl4JdbHiTFsQAgTjJMwghNEqSxN5D4ZKUYgIAUlAlLHFS9HUmdgjnR5DF0vAbDwIsABE2GQHJ4GAZgIEIiVTNi6hzKsiTEukwibnpYgSFHbQmTc6dNPnHSahiuLYoSyypJs1L7PSlQsvHVT3Py7zfOKkqTLK3lksqgd7O4M8MpPZzsonNS8s8rSdKLNrTI6pKKveWy8EHfqVEGurXMnMavJ8oA)

Comment: "So unless both of the arrays has the element you search for, it wont work" --- that's counter-intuitive. If both arrays have that element - then no point to use `includes` as it would be constant `true`.

Comment: @zerkms I didn't design typescript and i'm also not the one using as const.

Comment: I know :-) It looks like a too strict `ReadonlyArray<T>.includes` signature probably then.

Comment: @zerkms That's exactly what I want to say! My question is the mininal reproducible code, the real scenario has much more area members, we indeed do not have a common member between mutiple adjacencies.

Comment: @zerkms mhm. Thats what as const does -- strictifies (a word?) all the types. If the type was number[], then you could pass any number to the function.

Comment: @crazyones110 Your best bet AFAIK is to remove the as const.

Comment: @SharedRory "Thats what as const does" --- it only makes type inference stricter for a variable declaration. But it does not justify why a valid code does not type check.

Comment: @zerkms It changes the type for literals like 10 and "hello" from number and string to the actual value, thus not allowing you to pass "generic" numbers or strings aka any number and string. Since you leave it up to typescript to infer the types for both the arrays, it has to make the function work for either one. If it only works for 1 of them, it assigns the type never.

Comment: Once again: the problem is not in the variable declaration, it's in the `array::includes` signature. If `searchElement` was typed as `unknown` it would type check.

Comment: @zerkms The problem IS the variable declaration. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions. It clearly says "(e.g. no going from "hello" to string)". That means that the function can't be "generic" and just accept any number, instead it only accepts specific numbers. Now since it has to work for both of the arrays, unless there is an intersection between them, the type will be never.

Comment: I know what `as const` does and what literal types are. Once again: what is the purpose to make `searchElement: T` signature? Why not `searchElement: unknown`?

"That means that the function can't be "generic" and just accept any numbe" --- it does not mean that, there is nothing unique in literal types that invalidates properties of a generic function.

Comment: @SharedRory please read https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520 to see it **IS A BUG** in the declaration.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I have added an example to explain it. I don't think it's a bug since by doing as const, you agree to using literals over types like number and string.

Comment: "I don't think it's a bug since by doing as const, you agree to using literals over types like number and string." --- it's irrelevant, there is absolutely nothing wrong in having union or literal types. `Array::includes` signature is too restrictive which is reported as a bug and which is discussed in the bug tracker.

Comment: Please explain how it's too strict when you explicitly declare the variable as const.

Comment: It has **nothing to do** with the variable declaration, really. It's too strict because it requires `searchElement` be of the type `T`. Making it `any` or `unknown` would resolve the problem. Or https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520

Comment: Then why does [ 0, '0' ].includes(0) and [ 0, '0' ].includes('0') work?

Comment: It works because it passes type check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237619/discussion-between-zerkms-and-sharedrory).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @zerkms mentioning of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035048/251311, there seems to be two workarounds.

```js
const areas = {
  area1: {
    adjacencies: [2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  area2: {
    adjacencies: [6, 7, 8]
  }
} as const;

type ValueOf<T extends object> = T[keyof T];
type Values = ValueOf<ValueOf<typeof areas>>
type ElementUnion = Values[number];

let area: keyof typeof areas;
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
  area = "area1";
} else {
  area = "area2"
}

// first solution using type assertion
(areas[area].adjacencies as unknown as ElementUnion[]).includes(3); // works!

// second solution attempting using declaration merging
// from lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts, which I thick is quite ok
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  includes<T>(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): boolean;
}
```

`areas[area].adjacencies` is of type `readonly [2, 3, 4, 5] | readonly [6, 7, 8]`, which should be equivalent of `ReadonlyArray<2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8>`, and I made an experiment

```js
const readonlyArr = [1, 2, 3] as const;
readonlyArr.includes(3); // typescript successfully inferred T is 1 | 2 | 3
```

It seems like typescript is not able to convert union of readonly array to union of array members, which may be on purpose or not