# How to check if string is included in string literal type without using a type assertion?

Tags: typescript

I often have string literal types like this one:

```
const supportedLanguageTags = [
    "de-at",
    "de-ch",
    "de-de",
    "en-gb",
    "en-us",
] as const;

type LanguageTag = typeof supportedLanguageTags[number];

function isSupportedLanguageTag(tag: string): tag is LanguageTag {
    return (supportedLanguageTags as unknown as string[]).includes(tag);
}
```

Here I use an array to define the type but also to be able to check if a random string is included in the literal type.

However I really don't like the type assertion. Do you have suggestions to get rid of it?

One solution would be to use an object instead of an array like this:

```
const supportedLanguageTags = {
    "de-at": 1,
    "de-ch": 1,
    "de-de": 1,
    "en-gb": 1,
    "en-us": 1,
};

type LanguageTag = keyof typeof supportedLanguageTags;

function isSupportedLanguageTag(tag: string): tag is LanguageTag {
    return tag in supportedLanguageTags;
}
```

But here I don't like having to define a random value for every object property.

Comment: If you want to maintain type safety you could widen `supportedLanguageTags` to `readonly string[]` without a type assertion, with a cost of declare one new variable... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0LqOm).  If that meets your needs I'm happy to write up an answer.  If not, could you elaborate on what the issue is?  Also, does [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035048/2887218) address your situation?

Comment: @jcalz thanks. Yes that Q/A is the same situation. Using `readonly string[]` is already an improvement so feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in [the answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033854/why-does-the-argument-for-array-prototype-includessearchelement-need-the-same/53035048#53035048), the TypeScript typings for the `Array.prototype.includes()` call signature requires that the searched value be of the same type as the array elements.  If the array elements are of type `string`, then you can search for any `string`.  But if the array elements are of some *narrower* type than `string`, such as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then you will be prevented from searching for an arbitrary `string`.  This restriction is not really necessary for type safety; you should safely be able to search for something *wider* than the element types.

The issue [microsoft/TypeScript#26255](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) was opened to ask for support here, but it was closed as a duplicate of [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) which is about a way to represent supertype constraints.  TypeScript only has `extends`, where `U extends T` means that `U` must be some subtype of `T`.  For `Array<T>` you really want something like `includes<U super T>(searchElement: U): boolean`, where `U super T` means that `U` must be some supertype of `T`.  TypeScript doesn't have such syntax, though.  You can simulate it with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), like `includes<U extends (T extends U ? unknown : never)>(searchElement: U)`, but that's fairly complicated and is not part of the TypeScript typings for now.

---

One thing you *can* do here is to safely widen the type of your array to `readonly string[]`.  A [`readonly` array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) type is a supertype of `string` not known to have the mutating methods like `push()`.  An array of string literals can be safely widened to `readonly string[]` since you won't be modifying its contents, and it's always safer to read a value of any string literal type into something that expects a `string`.

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) allow both (safe) widening and (unsafe) narrowing.  But if you want to make sure that you haven't accidentally done an unsafe narrowing, you can forgo type assertions and instead [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a new variable.  Type annotations only support safe widenings.

That means you can write this:

```
function isSupportedLanguageTag(tag: string): tag is LanguageTag {
  const s: readonly string[] = supportedLanguageTags; // okay
  return s.includes(tag); // okay
}
```

And you have type safety.  Again, the `s` variable isn't really necessary, and a type assertion will reduce this to the terser `return (supportedLanguageTage as readonly string[]).includes(tag);` if you value concision over safety guarantees.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuAHRIBOUCmATAMgQzAHN49CMAVUiGAXhgG0BYAKBhgCIsMBaPKdgDQs2nHsAAWg4Ry7cuU1hwxhuhAEYKRy7vAgKAujDzVQkKAG4WLKAE9EGGPiIkylQrRi37IAGZwkKOjYTsSkFFT0YPAAtmoYqPqWzCw+8GDAUACW4DCZEADKAWiYuAShrqQAFFCkAFxwUKiZRACU9TXueY5lLuHuAN7SptBw9agYeFjgADY2DU1E9IZ0CMjFwT1hbhBJbONQ8KhgcAB0zcDT8FwQ1aQtSQC+QA)

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with `Array.prototype.includes` but I can't find the link.
In order to trick TypeScript you can overload your function. Since overloads works biveriantly TS will allow you use `tag is LanguageTag` return type:

```js
const supportedLanguageTags = [
  "de-at",
  "de-ch",
  "de-de",
  "en-gb",
  "en-us",
] as const;

type LanguageTag = typeof supportedLanguageTags[number];

function isSupported(tag: string): tag is LanguageTag
function isSupported(tag: any) {
  return supportedLanguageTags.includes(tag)
}


isSupported('hello') // ok
isSupported(42) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuAHRIBOUCmATAMgQzAHN49CMAVUiGAXhgG0AoGGAIiwwFo8pWAaZmw6dgAC36D2XDhJasMYToQBGstgs7wIEgLow81UJCgBuRoygBPRBhj4iJMpUK0YVmyABmcJCnTZ7YlIKKnoweABbZQxUHTNGT3gwYCgAS3AYVIgAZV80TCwACihSAC44KFRUogBKcpKXLLsCIKdSBKSU9LBMnLz-IobygksamABvQVQMKHhUHoRkfICWxxDCCAA6auAAG3gOCGLSGsYAX3NGLNylgcKAclEMXd2Qe7GAeg%20YEABrK76twKhQALAAmT7fGKoNBAA)

Yes, I have used `any`, but you are not allowed to call `isSupported` with number - only `string`.

Comment: I'm afraid I will have to disable our linter for the line using `any`, but I feel like this is the better approach than using a type assertion.