# Confusing type definition of Array.prototype.indexOf()

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

This is the current definition of `indexOf`:

```js
interface Array<T> {
    /**
     * Returns the index of the first occurrence of a value in an array, or -1 if it is not present.
     * @param searchElement The value to locate in the array.
     * @param fromIndex The array index at which to begin the search. If fromIndex is omitted, the search starts at index 0.
     */
    indexOf(searchElement: T, fromIndex?: number): number;
}
```

`indexOf` can only check the same element type `T`. This doesn't make sense when type of `searchElement` is a superset of `T`. For example:

```js
declare const arr: Array<'a'>;
declare const s: string;

arr.indexOf(s) // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'.(2345)
```

Here my target `arr` can only contain string `'a'`, but I want to check if a general string `s` is in that array(e.g., maybe we get the value from an API response, we don't know beforehand). Semantically, `indexOf` includes the non-existent case and returns `-1`. I'm confused because checking a general string against some known strings is a valid scenario: we just return `-1`.

What makes more sense to me is the following definition: we allow comparing `T` with its superset, not just `T`. So we can't compare `number` and `string`, but we can compare `'a'` and `string`. See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=6&ssc=23&pln=6&pc=24#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gFDLIC2WAkiACYQAeA8jAFzI4CqBAFAGcIcKAgAWAUQA2ESpzzJmkBgOTdkAfjXJOAIgDCcEAHIwyBAHtKABxERdASmQBeIiACulAEbRSAX1JSRgQpO3MLEAEzEShOdExcYzhjAgBuIIgQsMtI6M4oqFAAc0CAelLkRDB3OClSGIA6UEZWGD44B3qMJoZmNj4ARk7G5r624y8EY07ScsUma0zIei6oBuo6Fv6O1fXaXtbB4e6Ng-6JqZm5gAkLAHdKrwt3MxYvACslgS0aZDAxUAAa2QUmAlGAYGKfzEKEBECwyAsUGQIAsZie-yocDhyCEkQgDVmFVOWw4XF4gmEokkMjkyAUSggKkRHyWmhZnwQZnk82U9FU6i06j0hhMZksNjsjhcbk8PigGSyUBQOSilQwAziGGwOGIcE4E2MABpzAb6MY-GlAjEBj1SXw9QaEFM-McoLbRodiJgGFYnS63R6zm0BgAmADMnSAA).

```js
interface Array<T> {
  indexOf: <U>(searchElem: T extends U ? U : "Can't compare") => number
}
```

Is there a specific reason for the current type definition? If not, can we imporve the typing?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My question is, is there a specific reason for doing so? If not, can we improve the typing?

Comment: This feels related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690541/how-to-check-if-string-is-included-in-string-literal-type-without-using-a-type-a. Only that this question is about `indexOf` while the linked one is about `includes`. The answer does offer some explanation

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. In your example, the `arr` array can only contain `'a'`. Trying to search a random string in it **should** cause a compiler issue.

Comment: @TobiasS. - And even more related to the question it links to, nice one. :-)

Comment: The array in your example is clearly defined such that it can only contain `"a"` elements, so it doesn't make sense to search for, say, `"n"` in it -- you **know** it won't be there. It's exactly like searching for a number in a string array. Re your example of receiving a string from an API, that's perfectly fair point. You solve it the same way you'd solve any issue with receiving an overly-broad type and needing to narrow it before you could use it (for instance, receiving `any` or `unknown` when you need to assign to a `string` property): You use...

Comment: ...a type guard or similar to [narrow the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) before using it. In this *specific* case, the type guard would be enough to tell you whether the string was in the array, but that's just this specific case. :-) I often do that by starting with constant values and deriving the type from them. Let's expand your array a bit: `Array<"a" | "b">`. I'd probably do this in my implementation, where I derive the type and a type predicate from a list of values: https://tsplay.dev/wgQoMm

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks for sharing the link. It's exactly the same question.

Comment: @fjc I admit this is not the best example. This example is clearer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690541/how-to-check-if-string-is-included-in-string-literal-type-without-using-a-type-a

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the type guard example. That makes sense for the dynamic response case. My initial thought was to get rid of the whole `as` in `possibleValues as readonly string[]` which is discussed in the super type thread.

Comment: @Deerhound - :-) Glad that helped. I hadn't seen jcalz's answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690541/how-to-check-if-string-is-included-in-string-literal-type-without-using-a-type-a) (an answer which is characteristically useful). I shall forever be doing [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkkq9W) instead of [my original above](https://tsplay.dev/wgQoMm). :-D

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#includes) workaround