Typescript, Array includes error with: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"A" | "B"'
The distilled problem I have boils down to the following typescript code which errors out,
let arr = ["A","B"] as const // has to be const/readonly
function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
  return arr.includes(str);
}

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"A" | "B"'
the chat suggests a few solutions, all are crude on some level and "take extra steps", Is there really no better way that makes human sense?

Option 1: Narrow the Type of str

let arr = ["A", "B"] as const;

function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
  return arr.includes(str as "A" | "B");
}

This works because you’re telling TypeScript, "I know str can only be "A" or "B" for this comparison." which is false!

Option 2: Use a Set

const arrSet = new Set(["A", "B"] as const);

function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
  return arrSet.has(str);
}

That's an "overkill", includes can works without creating a new object!!

Option 3: Cast arr to a Looser Type

let arr = ["A", "B"] as const;

function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
  return (arr as readonly string[]).includes(str);
}

If you want to avoid modifying the function, you can cast arr to readonly string[], which loosens the type of includes, This approach sacrifices some type safety but resolves the error. I agree with the chat, it is a weird choice.
Are there no ways to implement this function without lying to the compiler or creating new objects?

"the chat suggests a few solutions", "I agree with the chat, it is a weird choice." Which chat? If you reference external communication, please link it. Without contex, we don't know what you had discussed.

"without lying to the compiler" option 3 does not lie: string[] is a more general type than ['A', 'B'], but it encompasses the latter (it's a super type).

• If "the chat" is an AI, then please [edit] to remove references to it, since such content is banned here. • widening arr to readonly string[] does not sacrifice type safety (although using as has the potential to do so; you can change it to const wideArr: readonly string[] = arr; if you don't want to type-assert), so that is the method I'd use. You are not lying to the compiler, so you've answered your own question. Please [edit] to fix these issues.

Or maybe even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690541/how-to-check-if-string-is-included-in-string-literal-type-without-using-a-type-a. I'm not sure which of the two dupes is the better fit

What about simply typing the array to contain strings? as const is not required to be able to use the array in a type predicate:
const arr: readonly string[] = ["A","B"];
function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
    return arr.includes(str);
}

(or simply const arr = ['A', 'B']; which is identical except for the readonly part)
You could also widen your type inside the function:
const arr = ["A","B"] as const;
function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
    const a: readonly string[] = arr;
    return a.includes(str);
}


Alternatively, change your method's implementation:
function isAorB(str: string): str is "A" | "B" {
    return str === 'A' || str === 'B';
}


const arr = ['A', 'B']; isn't the same as arr = ['A', 'B'] as const
I don't like the cast to string[] at all, these strings are specific "enum"-like even
as for the last solution, it's good for small number of elements that aren't intended to be changed that's not my usecase too
Thanks for the suggestions!

@YoraiLevi no, it's not the same. But since you want to check if a string array contains arbitrary strings, you'd want to type your array as string[] and not as a tuple. You could also do contains(str as any)
