# How can I use indexOf when the array's type is narrower than the query's type?

Tags: typescript, types, state-machine

I have a state machine where a subset of my states are "navigable", meaning the user can navigate forward and backward through them in sequence. Here's how I've represented it.

```ts
const NAVIGABLE_STATES = ["show_instructions", "lift_box", "turn_box"] as const;

type OverallState = 
  | "wait_for_connection"
  | "calibrate"
  | typeof NAVIGABLE_STATES[number];
  
/** Returns the next state upon navigation. */
function navigate(state: OverallState, direction: -1 | 1): OverallState {
  const idx = NAVIGABLE_STATES.indexOf(state);
  return NAVIGABLE_STATES[idx + direction];
}
```

I get this error on the argument to indexOf:

> Argument of type 'OverallState' is not assignable to parameter of type '"show_instructions" | "lift_box" | "turn_box"'.
>   Type '"wait_for_connection"' is not assignable to type '"show_instructions" | "lift_box" | "turn_box"'.

How can I search a narrowly typed array with a broadly typed query?

Comment: This is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033854/why-does-the-argument-for-array-prototype-includessearchelement-need-the-same) since `includes` and `indexOf` have similar issues.  Let me know if that answer explains things; if not, please [edit] the question to elaborate on any unsatisfied remaining problems.  Note that the easiest thing to do here is probably [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYBr3w) or else [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnXneW) if you don't like type assertions.

Comment: ^^ with the added dimension that you need to handle `"wait_for_connection"` and `"calibrate"`, since they aren't in the array but are members of the `OverallState` type.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, you provided exactly what I need.