# Is there a way to keep type inference in union types from type guards inside a function?

Tags: typescript, types, typeguards

Let's say I have three types (and a union one)

```js
type A = {
    type: 'a'
    title: string
    description: string
}

type B = {
    type: 'b'
    title: string
}

type C = {
    type: 'c'
    description: string
}

type D = A | B | C
```

I know I can get a correct type inference with the === operator

```js
function logger(t: D) {
    if (t.type === 'a' || t.type === 'b') console.log(t.title) // no problems here
    if (t.type === 'a' || t.type === 'c') console.log(t.description) // no problems here
}
```

However, would it be possible to write an utility function:

```js
function matches<T extends { type: string }>(t: T, types: T['type'][]) : boolean {
    return types.includes(t.type)
}
```

So I can do this without errors?

```js
function logger(t: D) {
    if (matches(t, ['a', 'b'])) console.log(t.title) // Property 'title' does not exist on type D
    if (matches(t, ['a', 'c'])) console.log(t.description) // Property 'description' does not exist on type D
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write `matches()` as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) so that the compiler understands your intent for the `true`/`false` output of the function to narrow the type of the `t` parameter.

Here's one way to do it:

```
function matches<T extends { type: string }, K extends string>(
    t: T, types: K[]
): t is Extract<T, { type: K }> {
    const widenedTypes: readonly string[] = types;
    return widenedTypes.includes(t.type);
}
```

This is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) both in `T`, the type of `t`, but also `K`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements of `types`.  The return type is `Extract<T, {type: K}>`, which uses [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter the union type `T` to just those constituents assignable to `{type: K}`.

Note that the compiler will complain about `types.includes(t.type)` because the elements of `types` are narrower than `t.type`.  The way I deal with that is to first (safely) widen `types` from `K[]` to `readonly string[]` and then call `includes()` on that.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53033854/2887218) and its answers for more information.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
function logger(t: D) {
    if (matches(t, ['a', 'b'])) console.log(t.title) // okay
    if (matches(t, ['a', 'c'])) console.log(t.description) // okay
}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFTVSQFxQHIBDA9LbAS2ABsJ8BnYAJwoDsBzMrAEwnoGMWYYBQD2rBszac0AX3Toc0AEIJkXTEvwEARqQxYRNOlEYsO6eWkXhoAYTWoDm29v77yvAUJHjJ5mSsbSCgAETU4AB8oVWi7BWtEgDMAV1Z+X1YoAFsiYH4ACz4AHgAVKAgAD2AIVm56ZGxXUykOKFkAGigAaQrq2vqWgIA+AAoNbHxSrqV6fG6AbQBddABKfGAoCgaAUWqmIgyyrqQmvB724fVnKH5xRigAdwpeVghuUts5qCYIIm5xNQQENpMs1LMANwTX7AFJMLLPV7vT6QegAOjY-GoKS8o2AaKUqyhcgS6FS6UyUGoonY7AgTDx+FCq2u5AoSSgo1y+SK9DxXQWxAIXV0BCWqxZd1Y9FEtDR1PYeIJVFoLIA9GqoKIANZEEATdmc7mFPj8qCCkgi9ziyX3WUQeU0pVeQQUYRiVjqzU6vWWdBAA)

Comment: It worked like a charm! Just a little note, if I change `K extends string` to `K extends T['type']`, vscode/playground will be able to suggest the strings 'a' | 'b' | 'c' when calling the function, thank you!