# TypeScript: Restrict function parameter value to values of array within dynamic variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a simple react hook that returns a function. I would like this function to only accept values from an array that gets passed into the hook.

Heres the hook:

```
type Options<P> = {
  pathname: string;
  rootPath: string;
  paths: P;
};

export const useLayoutPaths = <P extends string[]>(options: Options<P>) => {
  const { pathname, rootPath, paths } = options;

  if (paths.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("paths must be a non-empty array.");
  }

  const currentPath = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  const value = paths.includes(currentPath) ? currentPath : paths[0];

  const getPath = (name: typeof paths[number]): string =>
    `${rootPath}/${String(name)}`;

  return { value, getPath };
};
```

I would like the getPath function to only allow values that exist within the "paths" variable.

Heres my current usage:

```
const { value, getPath } = useLayoutPaths({
  pathname,
  rootPath: `/department/${orgId}`,
  paths: ["trends", "comments"],
});

console.log(getPath("trends")) <-- Only allow "trends" or "comments"
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnKKxm) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @jcalz Thats perfect. Please create an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the compiler to keep track of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) of the strings passed in as the `paths` property.  Unfortunately this did not happen with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) constraint like `P extends string[]`.  One way to increase the likelihood that the compiler will treat `"foo"` as being of type `"foo"` instead of type `string` is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) a generic type parameter to `string`.  So `P extends string` will work better.  We can just have `P` be the type of the elements of `paths` instead of `paths` itself, like this:

```
export const useLayoutPaths = <P extends string>(options: Options<P[]>) => {
   // impl
};
```

This will work as desired, but the compiler doesn't like letting you look up a `string` in an array of `P`.  See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53033854/2887218) for more information.  The easiest way to deal with that is to widen `paths` from `P[]` to `readonly string[]` before using `includes()`:

```
export const useLayoutPaths = <P extends string>(options: Options<P[]>) => {
  const { pathname, rootPath, paths } = options;

  if (paths.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("paths must be a non-empty array.");
  }

  const currentPath = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  const value = (paths as readonly string[]).includes(currentPath) ? currentPath : paths[0];

  const getPath = (name: typeof paths[number]): string =>
    `${rootPath}/${String(name)}`;

  return { value, getPath };
};
```

And now things work as you want:

```
console.log(getPath("trends")) // okay
getPath("oops"); // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-fljf5Q1hrNYFQSun6se2o3lUfRMYWonH26vyJysWJrTheXxVqBrYwMVvANBreLV1T4lMmJA9bpIHhBePu9YDnxTpIpVGoqBIADWthIG4k6xEYF3fCgB-cyz0AEISEA)

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense now.