# Why typescript enum is seen as possibly undefined in strict mode? How to fix?

Tags: typescript, strict

I'm getting an error from Typescript (`4.8.2`) **STRICT**:

```
Argument of type 'State | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'State'. ts(2345)
```

using this code:

```
enum State {
  Completed = "COMPLETED",
  Discontinued = "DISCONTINUED",
}

type Player = {
  description: Scalars["String"];
  state: State;
  team?: Maybe<Team>;
};

let player: Partial<Player>;

const isOK = [State.Completed, State.Discontinued].includes(player.state);
```

How can I fix?

It's because of `Partial<Player>`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `Partial<Player>` might not have a defined `state`, and TypeScript's typings for the `includes()` method of arrays requires that the searched item be assignable to the array element types.  (See [Why does the argument for Array.prototype.includes(searchElement) need the same type as array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53033854/2887218))

The easiest way to deal with this is to eliminate the possibility of `undefined` by checking for it explicitly before you use `includes()`:

```
const isOK = (player.state !== undefined) &&
    [State.Completed, State.Discontinued].includes(player.state);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=16#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzsKBvAsAKCjqBhAewgAcAbYZAEygF4oAiPAeQFkAFAGQFEAVLgEXoAaLLij8AlgGcAxgRBwJ4YNTr1+ASRjMAcjw06AqgOFYAvlixwAnsRRtSCa8ABOtNKNxTEyAFywfYABucxDMLEpgGUcXFHI4KDInV382BBdFBFIAHgdklwA+MKw5EG8oaSYAaXcACiTnFwA6byQUAEIaOjAQSIAzJRUASigAMlHPHABteDamwhJ4lSEAuclZeUVlSgBdJqVosEipesdGlsChoKA)